# scrapy from a shell script

Tags: bash, unix, scrapy

I can't get scrapy to run from shell script, I've seen several other examples in stackoverflow and nothing seems to work.

```
ubuntu 14
scrapy 1.1
```

script is this -

```
#!/bin/bash
#run scrapy from cron
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
cd /home/money/hybrid/threatexpert
# tried cd ./home/money/Documents/hybrid/threatexpert #didn't work
pwd
which scrapy
scrapy crawl threatexpert
```

job in cron is this - 
27 16 * * * /home/money/Documents/hybrid/threatexpert/scrapythreat.sh > /home/money/Documents/hybrid/threatexpert.log 2>&1

the path the the script is 
/home/money/Documents/hybrid/threatexpert/scrapythreat.sh

the error I get is -

```
/home/money/Documents/hybrid/threatexpert/scrapythreat.sh: line 4: cd: /home/money/hybrid/threatexpert: No such file or directory
/home/money
/usr/local/bin/scrapy
Scrapy 1.1.0 - no active project

Unknown command: crawl

Use "scrapy" to see available commands
threatexpert.log (END)
```

I've been looking at this for a day or two now and would really appreciate suggestions.

Comment: You say `/home/money/Documents/threatexpert` everywhere else but the `cd` tries to go to `/home/money/threatexpert` without the `Documents` subdirectory.  Voting to close as simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey who knew you could change directories right in cron --

```
35 17 * * * cd /home/money/Documents/hybrid/threatexpert; ./scrapythreat.sh > /home/money/Documents/hybrid/threatexpert.log 2>&1
```